# SSIS insert at the same time 3 entries

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hello so in my SSIS data flow and I have 3 flat files which need to be put in 1 table (ole db). I need to insert them at the same time and on the same row. How to do this ?

3 entries for 1 destination but I need to insert them at the same time on the same row:

[image]

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: The easiest thing that would help me is, insert my 3 entering columns to get directly the 3 outgoing columns. Right now I have 3 columns that are splitted appart since they come from 3 different files. I want to have the same thing as if I was taking 3 columns from 1 file. The fact that I work with 3 entries at the same time... Do you understand

Comment: Please do not link to screenshots. Instead **explain** in text what exactly you intend to achieve, what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: @comptegratuit03 I, for one, don't understand at all what you're trying to ask.   Do you know a native English-speaker who might be able to help you re-write your question?   Otherwise, edit your question and show a very clear example of the specific thing you are trying to do and where you are stuck.   The screenshot currently in your question doesn't tell us anything except you have 3 objects named "Trier" and a Destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have Col1 in File1, Col2 in File2 and Col3 in File3 and you need to import them all Col1, Col2, Col3 into one table. You are correct, you need to use Merge Join which needs a column to join on. You do need to do some intermediate steps, there's no direct way to do that AFAIK. I can see two options:

1. Create on-the-fly row_number column for each source and then do
   merge join. Use [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87196/how-do-i-set-up-a-derived-column-transformation-to-get-row-number-in-ssis-2014) for script component.
2. Create temporary tables with Auto incrementing Identity column for
    each of the sources which you can then do merge join with.